Finding the file path to the modules imported by another file
I want to build a dependency graph for a python project. I know there are already some tools out there, but my approach has some specifications that does not make easy their use.
Right now I can parse the import statements of a file using tree-sitter and obtain the module names, as well as the objects, like so:
from module_name import object  or import module_name(example of an import)
I want to be able to, given this information, get the path to the file where the module_name or object is defined. This is sometimes tricky due to the flexibility of import statements in python.
Is there any library or tool that, given a project and a specific file of that project, can output the paths to the direct dependencies of that file? Note that I cannot modify any file in the project
I have tried an approach by creating a file with the same imports and using inspect to print the file paths, but it is not a pretty solution and might not cover all the corner cases.
I have also heard of pydeps but, from what I've tried, it seems to do more that just direct dependencies and I fear it might be too complex for my use case.

Look at the sys.modules dict and the module class

I looked into it but doesn't that require me to change or run the file in question? I was looking for a more static approach. But I'm still looking into it , maybe there's something that I'm missing
